# How to Fetch Custom Fields In Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I want to group all similar hero names and sum the total of their 'killCount' relative to that name like:

```
--heroname--   --killCount-- 
Guson             999
Garen             934
Magnus            445
```

I have a Hero Entity which has these fields (but I dont intend to fetch all columns from SQL, I only need heroname and killCount)

```
Long heroid;
String heroname;
Integer killCount;
String heroClass;
String faction;
```

In my repository class I want to create a JPA query where I want to fetch rows where in I group them by 'heroname' column and the corresponding SUM/TOTAL of that hero's 'killCount'.

This [blog by Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-queries-custom-result-with-aggregation-functions) suggest I create an interface. But the blog doesnt show how to actually use that in the app controller or service class. It just says create an interface.

Here's my current repository class:

```
public interface HeroRepository extends JpaRepository<Hero,Long>{

    @Query( value = "SELECT h.heroname , SUM(h.killCount) FROM Heroes AS h GROUP BY h.heroname ORDER BY h.heroname",nativeQuery = true)     
    List<IHero> findAllHeroByGroupName();
}
```

Am I doing this right?

**Service class:**

```
public class HeroService {  
    @Autowired  HeroRepository heroRepository;      
    public List<IHero> findAllHeroByGroupName() {       
        return heroRepository.findAllHeroByGroupName();     
    } 
}
```

**Interface**

```
public interface IHero {
    String getHeroName();
    Integer getTotalKillCounts();
}
```

**--UPDATE[SOLVED]--**

When I do this

```
List<IHero> heroList = heroService.findAllHeroByGroupName();
```

and print via loop:

```
for(IHero hero: heroList){
   System.out.println(hero.getHeroName);
   System.out.println(hero.getTotalKillCounts);
}
```

`hero.getHeroName` contains correct value while `hero.getTotalKillCounts` contains `NULL`.  Why is that? Im almost there.

**ANSWER:** You need to use alias equal to the field name in your Entity. So I used alias for `SUM(killCount)` to 'killCount' only. Bamm!

```
@Query( value = "SELECT h.heroname , SUM(h.killCount) as killCount FROM Heroes AS h GROUP BY h.heroname ORDER BY h.heroname",nativeQuery = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

in the repository try to specify the parameter heroName and update the query like this by adding where clause:-

```
public interface HeroRepository extends JpaRepository<Hero,Long>{

    @Query( value = "SELECT h.heroname , SUM(h.killCount) FROM Heroes AS h where h.heroname = ?1 GROUP BY h.heroname ORDER BY h.heroname",nativeQuery = true)     
    //code below will cause errors, I need to use interface says Baeldung
    List<Hero> findAllHeroByGroupName(String heroName);
}
```

Comment: hey thanks mate. but my inention is to fetch all heroes grouped by 'heroname' and the sum of 'killCount' relative to that name.

Comment: ok got u can you add your serviceClass to the question pls ?